# Does the RingCentral Call Log API Return a "Missed" Value?

Tags: calllog, ringcentral

In the RingCentral Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com) and endpoint apps, the call log display shows whether a call was Inbound, Outbound or Missed.

In looking at the API Reference for the Call Log API, it seems that it only sends back Inbound or Outbound for "Direction". Does the developer Call Log API return a "Missed" value? Is there another way to get this information via the Call Log API?

Ref: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCallLog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question appears to be in reference to the Online Account Portal UI's "Type" column as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

The web UI's "Type" column shows Inbound, Outbound or Missed. This can be generated by using the response properties for both `direction` and `result`.

- `direction` API response property will be `Inbound` or `Outbound`
- `result` API response property is an enumerated value that includes `Missed` and other values including `Voicemail` which is the example screenshot. A full list is available in the link below:

Ref: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#ResultStatusValues

Here is an example response:

```
{
    "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log?view=Simple&showBlocked=true&withRecording=false&dateFrom=2018-08-27T06:18:00.000Z&page=1&perPage=100",
    "records": [
        {
            "uri": "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/call-log/22222222?view=Simple",
            "id": "22222222",
            "sessionId": "33333333",
            "startTime": "2018-08-27T17:38:12.634Z",
            "duration": 27,
            "type": "Voice",
            "direction": "Inbound",
            "action": "Phone Call",
            "result": "Missed",
            "to": {
                "phoneNumber": "+16505550101"
            },
            "from": {
                "phoneNumber": "+16505550102",
                "name": "LOS ALTOS    CA",
                "location": "Los Altos, CA"
            }
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [blog](https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/visualize-your-business-communications-history-2c81f85c324a) to find out more information you can find from the call log.